# taking AudioBuffer samples

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-audio

i am trying to take the audio buffer samples in real time( resolution of ms)

i am using this function, but it gives me error.

```
 AudioBufferList *bufferList = NULL;
    AudioBuffer audioBuffer = bufferList->mBuffers[0];
    int bufferSize = audioBuffer.mDataByteSize / sizeof(SInt32);
    SInt32 *frame = audioBuffer.mData;
    SInt32  signalInput[22050];
    for( int i=0; i<bufferSize; i++ )
    {
        SInt32 currentSample = frame[i];
        *(signalInput +i) = currentSample;
        NSLog(@"Total power was: %ld ",currentSample);
    }
```

what am i doning wrong here ?
i only need to get the audio samples .i dont want 2 pages code(such as in the app doc)

thanks .

Answer (score 0):

What you want is inconsistent with what you are trying to do.  A NULL bufferlist can produce no samples.

You need the two+ pages of code to properly configure the Audio Session and the RemoteIO Audio Unit (etc.) in order to get what you are trying to get.  Otherwise there are no samples.  The phone won't even turn on audio recording or know how to set up the recording (there a bunches of options) before turning it on.  Study the docs and deal with it.

Comment: i had correct that NULL i have put it here by mistake. so in order to grab the buffers data in real time (useconds/mseconds) i can use the remoteIO ? the lake app docs are full of so many kinds of audio stuff so u cant know whats the best for you and what you really need. I need to get real time audio signal in a micro-seconds.